# SQL flag for matching values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, count, case, matching

I am looking to make a flag for customers who have bought the same item twice, but on different days.

Essentially I am looking to make a flag when duplicate values are found in some columns, but not all.

```
Matching columns = customer, product
Unmatching column = order date
```

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG5ZV.png)

[example outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B6Cy.png)

I have tried

```
SELECT
    customer,
    order date,
    product,
    COUNT_IF(product = product) OVER (PARTITION BY customer 
                                      ORDER BY product ASC 
                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS repeat_flag
FROM 
    table
```

which is close but it doesn't account for matching values on the same day.

Comment: If you want people to answer with tested solutions, please provide sample data in text format, not images. Also your question asks for 'purchased twice', but the column name implies or more times (repeat_flag)

Comment: Always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. `COUNT_IF` is not a standard SQL function and hence not available in every DBMS. So which DBMS do you want an answer for?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the desired outcome using the following

```
    SELECT
  customer,
  order_date,
  product,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer, product) > 1 AND COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer, product, order_date) = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer, product, order_date) > 1 THEN 0
    ELSE 0
  END AS new_column
FROM your_table_name
```